# Indexing Python object not allowed without gil?

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, parallel-processing, cython

```
from cython.parallel import prange

@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
cpdef int find_indices(int[::1] values, int[::1] source, int[::1] rep, int lim):
cdef int num_values = values[:lim]
cdef int num_source = source.shape[0]

i:int
for i in prange(num_values, nogil=True):
    j:int
   
    for j in prange(num_source):
        if source[j] == values[i]: 
            if rep[j] <10: return -1

return 1

def main():
    values:int[::1] = np.array([2, 3, 1, 5, 4])
    search_array:int[::1] = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    rep_array:int[::1] = np.array([11, 15, 18, 3, 2])
    limit=3

    result_index = find_indices(values, search_array, rep_array, limit)

    if result_index == 1:
        print(f"Valid {result_index}")
    else:
        print("No valid.")
```

```
if rep[j] <10: return -1
cyt.pyx:347:22: Indexing Python object not allowed without gil
```

Hi I want to know how to return -1 without this error.
rep is a cython memory view, so I dont know what is the python object, could be "return" what is refering to?

If this does not have a closed solution, then how to proceed?

Comment: I think it's pointing at the wrong place and `rep` is your Python object

Answer (score 0):

There's a long list of things wrong with your code. You're showing the *last* error message when it's usually better to start with the first. Most are fairly trivial though so I'll skip them and just show the non-obvious one.

The main one is:

```
i:int
# and
j:int
```

When `int` is used as a *type annotation*, Cython assumes a Python integer. This is different from a `cdef`declaration.

The reason is that

1. Type annotations aren't necessarily aimed at Cython, so Cython should use them cautiously and not change the behaviour of the code.
2. Python ints and C ints behave differently - a Python `int` can take almost unlimitedly large numbers.

To use a C int, make the annotation `i: cython.int` instead.

The "without gil" error is because you're trying to index `rep` with a Python object.